# Set attribute into JSP PageContext for use in EL from a Filter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

How can I put an attribute into the JSP PageContext for the current request (so that it becomes accessible via `${myVar}` ) from a Filter that runs before the JSP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I may be missing something, but:

- you have the `ServletRequest` object in the filter
- call `request.setAttribute("myVar", value);`
- call `chain.doFilter(request, response);`

Comment: Okay. That was easy. :-) I thought request attributes and the variables in EL were unrelated ...

Comment: @Thilo: `${foo}` does behind scenes `pageContext.findAttribute("foo")` and see what its javadoc says ;) http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29